# How does the jet stream affect weather in Europe?

Tags: meteorology, pressure, cyclone

I researched how mid lattitude cyclones form and found it has to do with the jet stream, which is above the polar front. The pressure difference between the warm and cold air causes a pressure gradient and is tilted to the right due to the coriolis effect.

How does the jet stream affect weather (e.g. cyclones) in europe? How is it related to the divergence in the jet stream? Also, why is the divergence aloft created? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You kind of answer your own question. What additional information do you expect in an answer?

Comment: I changed the question a bit; hopefully it is more in line with the intent of the OP